# ASPX Routing URL not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I'm using the tradicional Routing library in Global.asax to use friendly URL's, but now i'm trying to route with params, and i can't it says:

> Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "marca/{nome}", "~/marca.aspx");
```

I use it in jquery to create automaticly controls:
...

```
"</div>" +
   "<div class='pull-right'>" +
      "<a href='/produto/" + res[i].id_produto + "' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm hidden-xs'>Mais Informação</a>" +
   "</div>" +
```

...

and then when this control is a user clicks and shows that error

Comment: this seem to be correct. can you show the code how you are using it in your aspx page ?

Comment: done up in the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will show one of my code with JQuery that is working:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("profile", "profile/{ID}", "~/profile.aspx");
```

And i'm using it in my autocomplete as

```
.append("<a href='/profile/" + item.userId + "'>" + item.fullName + "</a>")
```

And it's working well. Check also that the binding value are ok !